# Tomcat 10 deploy a legacy J2EE war through manager

Tags: legacy-code, java-ee-8, tomcat10

Following the docs on Tomcat I had no problem either migrating my war during build or deploying it in the **webapps-javaee** directory; the migration went just fine.

But I see no option in the manager to deploy a war as legacy; if you try to do that, the app is deployed just fine but it will of course fail when it calls a legacy API.

Thus it seems that the only way is to either **migrate the jar before deploy** or **deploy copying a war file manually** (or with a script, but still far from ideal).
Is there a way to have a manager deployed war migrated automatically, just as if it was copied in the legacy directory?

Of course the perfect solution would be to migrate the code... or to not use tomcat 10 until you feel like doing what's needed to make it work flawlessly.

Comment: Sounds like a small feature request for Tomcat Manager.

Comment: I don't think you have any other option than migrate code or lower Tomcat.

"Applications that run on Tomcat 9 and earlier will not run on Tomcat 10 without changes. Java EE based applications designed for Tomcat 9 and earlier may be placed in the $CATALINA_BASE/webapps-javaee directory and Tomcat will automatically convert them to Jakarta EE and copy them to the webapps directory. This conversion is performed using the Apache Tomcat migration tool for Jakarta EE tool which is also available as a separate download for off-line use."